# apt-get -f install gives ominous warning about essential package (Trusty)

Tags: 14.04, apt

I have unmet dependencies in my system. This happened while I was trying to install `lib32stdc++6` for android studio. I tried some solution from the internet and ended up with unresolved dependencies. Now when I try to do: `apt-get -f install`

I get the following warning:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  foomatic-filters libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt libapt-pkg4.12 (due to apt) libstdc++6 (due to apt)
```

As silly as it sounds/is, I do not have a backup, and therefore would not want to render my system unbootable, and unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `apt` will not make your system unbootable but it would be a very bad decision.

Look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see which packages you have installed and removed that led to this situation, and carefully reverse every action.